# Using MDIParent forms in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, datagridview

I have inserted an MDIParent form in my project.  There is a datagridview on it.  When I add data to it (on parent form) and then open a child form through Parent form, it displays the datagridview, which it should but there are two unwanted things:

1. It also takes all the data which I entered on Parent form's datagrid view
2. When I make change to data on child form, the effect also transfers to the parent form's datagridview.

Please advise how to make controls on parent forms the data changes of which limit to the current form only, not on all children and parent forms.

Comment: Don't put controls on the MDIParent, they will overlap the child windows.  You can set their Dock property to dock them to an edge, but that of course won't work well for a grid.  You'll need to display it in a child form.

Comment: I think what you are seeing is that when the child form loads the controls you added to the parent are on top of the child form. If you move the child form the parent controls will remain in place. The child form and its controls will always be under the parent. You might be able to set Visible=False at the proper times to hide the parent controls. You could place all the parent controls in a container and hide the container.

Comment: The ToolStripContainer should do the trick - the child windows will appear under the container but if the child is maximized it will be constrained to the remaining space on the parent form. Place your parent controls on the container.

Comment: I think i could not explain my point.  I want to display and use controls on parent forms but each child form should use them independently.  For example, I have designed a form to make invoice.  Now the purpose is when I open child form, it should also make the invoice the same way as parent does but with its own data.  Only datasets should be common for all parent and child